# How to create/handle jQuery UI dialog that updates model

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a requirement to ask a question when a certain scenario happens on my MVC 4 view.

When that scenario is true, I simply want to have a jQuery UI dialog pop up modally. That dialog will simply have two radio buttons for "WidgetType" (Purple or Blue).

The viewModel has a property for SelectedWidgetType (that has a default value).

I simple am looking for the best way to handle updating the underlying model with the selection a user picks in the dialog.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

NOTE: I am using this overly simple example as the basis for other dialogs that will have more fields on them that also update the underlying model.

Creating the dialog isn't the hard part, but I am struggling with getting the values.

Comment: Did you consider MVC 4's [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? APIs are very similar to controllers, but provide RESTful operations on the model that can be invoked from Javascript.

Comment: Alright, I'll bite. How about providing a sample?

Comment: Sure. If the tutorials from the link I provided are not extensive enough, there is a [very complete example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424461/Implementing-Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-from-JQuery) on codeproject.

Comment: Thanks for the example, much appreciated. Still doesn't resolve my question in regards to the jQuery UI dialog confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User jQuery's AJAX post method.

Create a view model JavaScript object on the front end that maps to the parameters of your data model. This view model object can be triggered to get updated each time the user changes his selected options by calling an update method via the change event handles of each form element.

Pass it back to the server controller by packing it into a JSON object using json2.js

If you want a full framework/elegant solution look at using knockout.js which simulates most of this for you... !